# Get second highest value in a table

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

```
id value
1   50
2   60
3   55

select max(value) from tablename;
```

Generally we know, we will get 60, but I need the next value 55.

How do I get the value 55 using SQL?

Comment: This is basically the same question as https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61140/find-the-second-highest-value-from-a-subquery-or-derived-table/302809#302809.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming the highest value only occurs once, another way would be to use [`OFFSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) (SQL Server 2012 or later):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY column DESC 
OFFSET 1 ROW 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 24):

To get the second highest *distinct* value in the table you can use

```
SELECT MIN(value)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) value
        FROM   tablename
        ORDER  BY value DESC)T
/*If only one distinct value return nothing. */
HAVING MIN(value) <> MAX(value);
```

Answer (score 13):

A generic solution can be like below:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1
        , Col2
        , <AnyColumns>
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <AnyColumns>) AS RowNum
    FROM <YourTable>
    WHERE <YourCondition>
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 2 -- Or any condition which satisfies your problem
```

Here you can also define the range like `RowNum >= 10 AND RowNum <= 20`. And it will give you 10th to 20th rows with all required columns.

Answer (score 7):

You have the usual top trick such as:

```
select top 1 *
from (
    select top 2 *
    from my_table
    order by value desc
    ) t 
order by value asc
```

Or you can also use CTE like:

```
with CTE as
(
select value, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value desc) as ord_id
from my_table
)
select value
from CTE
where ord_id = 2
```

Or, if you use recent version of SQLServer (>= 2012), the [lag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh231256.aspx) function.

```
SELECT  top 1  lag(value, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY value)  
FROM my_table
order by value desc
```

Answer (score 5):

I will do like this:

```
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM tablename
WHERE value < (SELECT MAX(value)
               FROM tablename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function as well.  If you want to get the 2nd entry when ordered by your target value, you can do:

```
SELECT value 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY value DESC) as RN,
        value
    FROM my_table
) d
WHERE RN = 2
```

Now if you want to get the 2nd highest value and you have duplicates, you might want to group by the value entry so that you only get distinct values.

```
SELECT value 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY value DESC) as RN,
        value
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY value
) d
WHERE RN = 2
```

You should be able to modify this approach to include a `MIN(id)` in the inner select if you need to know the ID of the first record with the 2nd highest value (assuming you had a data set with two 60s and two 55s)

Comment: For the second highest it's easier to just replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `DENSE_RANK()` - you also get all the other columns for free. No need to use `GROUP BY`.